# Workspace is Closed Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I opened the Eclipse app and then I got this error message:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiabt.png)
And I can't do anything on the blank workspace:
[Blank Workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODEH0.png)
I opened Eclipse a few days ago and it worked normally.
I didn't do/know anything about plugins.

I tried to import a project so I can edit the project but that didn't work.
I was trying to open a GUI from Swing this morning and I went to the eclipse-workspace, I thought I can just open a class like in Python, it doesn't work so I opened the Eclipse app and I got the error.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Does _Window > Perspective > Rest Perspective..._ fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The main eclipse screen is not called the 'workspace', but I can see how that can be confusing.

In eclipse parlance, a 'workspace' is, more or less, a working folder: The place on disk where eclipse stores everything. When you start eclipse, you choose your workspace directory. This should optimally be a subdir of your user account's directory on your OS (for example, on macs, `/Users/yourname/workspace` is good, on windows perhaps `C:\Users\yourname\workspace`, on linuxen for example `/home/yourname/workspace`).

This dir will contain a few eclipse settings files (there will be a subdir named `.settings` inside the workspace dir), and is the default location for every project you make (when you pick `File > New...` from the menu and make a new project, the directory it suggests is inside this workspace, and I recommend you put your projects there.

You can ask eclipse to not ask for workspace folder on startup. This is in settings (so if you want that back to fix this problem, you can go into eclipse's settings and change this, or you can just directly do so: In the `File` menu there's a `Switch workspace` option. Choose that and fix your path.

I'm guessing you're getting this error because you did this sequence of events:

- You started eclipse. It asked for a workspace
- You typed something in there that is an invalid path, or, it was valid at the time but does not currently exist: You deleted it, moved it, or you created it on a volume that isn't currently present (for example, you put your workspace on a USB stick and the stick isn't currently in the machine).
- You also checked the 'always use this workspace and no longer ask for workspace on startup' checkbox.

And now we're here.

Without a workspace dir eclipse doesn't know which projects exist. You can't use eclipse if it has no workspace dir. Thus, in eclipse, File - Change workspace, and fix that first. As part of picking a workspace, eclipse effectively reboots so don't worry about that.

The layout of an eclipse window is called a 'perspective'. Yours is currently entirely blank (your question said: "Blank workspace". What you meant was "blank perspective").

I think that's just because eclipse has no workspace so doesn't know what to show in this perspective, or even which perspectives are available. Hence, I think you'll be fine once you do the above.

However, if not: You've been closing views in the default perspective and eclipse remembers this stuff. You'll need to re-open them. You do this by picking all the various relevant views from the 'Window > View' menu, or just go Window > Reset perspective, to get the factory default java perspective (with the 'outline', 'package explorer', 'console', 'problems', and so on views open).

If you still see no windows, then you've been closing views. Eclipse remembers (but, it remembers by writing a settings file to the workspace so I doubt you'll still see a perspective
Once you've done that, *if* eclipse